# MonoTouch Running differently on IOS Emulator than on IPad

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, xamarin

I'm having issues around my app (basically a modified Mobile World Conference) app when I run it on the `IOS Emulator` in windows, verses running it directly on the `IPad` itself.  I understand that there is a different process or involved so I don't expect it to be exactly the same.

In specific, I'm getting errors around initializing sql databases (SqlLite) with errors being

> "Object Not Defined"

When I try and single step debug to the device, I get errors that feel like somehow the stack has been corrupted and I can not even debug into methods.

My question is, what are the types of differences I can look for and how to debug them?  There must be some pattern of things that cause issues, I just have no idea what that is or how to figure it out.  I'm use to my c# code just working on x86.

Comment: Please provide some code to help solve your issue (especially, code which "initializing sql databases").

Comment: How are you running the iOS emulator in Windows?

Comment: I'm running the IOS Emulator in windows launched by monodevelop. Regarding code, it's not just Creating table, it's other things that crash in a strange way (like a LINQ statement that simply gets the first record in a collection).  Specifically, I'm asking for the kind of things that can cause the emulator to run differently.  I'm not asking for help with this specific problem (because I don't have a good specific case without adding tons of code)

Answer (score 0):

What causes simulator to behave differently? Simulator is not constrained in memory usage like a real device so you're likely to hit memory warnings on the device (and crash if you don't handle them properly). The code itself, however, runs faster so race conditions between threads are more likely, so watch out for that. Don't talk to database from different threads, or at least use proper locking. And of course there are [AOT limitations](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT#Limitations) which occur only on the device. Your LINQ problem sounds like a AOT problem to me.